# Read access denied for Lead, controller action methods may not execute

Tags: apex, community, permissions

i am getting '**Read access denied for Lead, controller action methods may not execute.**' error when i run my test class.

i have a controller class which creates a Lead record and the constructor for it is below:

```
public NewEngagementRequestController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        try{
            LeadObj = (Lead)controller.getRecord();

            Usr = [SELECT Id,AccountId,ContactId,Name FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()]; 
            account = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id =: usr.AccountId];
            contact = [SELECT FirstName, LastName, MobilePhone,Email FROM Contact where Id =: Usr.ContactId];  

            if(contact != null){
                Fullname = contact.FirstName + ' ' + contact.LastName;    
            }

            EngagementId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cloneEngId');

            if(String.isNotBlank(EngagementId) && EngagementId != null){
                EngagementsObj = [SELECT Engagement_Title__c, Engagement_Overview__c, Test_Scenarios_provided_by_Client__c, 
                                  Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Testing_Type__c, 
                                  Known_Compatibility_Coverage__c, Website_URL_to_be_tested__c 
                                  FROM Engagements__c WHERE Id =: EngagementId];

                if(EngagementsObj != null){

                    LeadObj.Engagement_Title__c = EngagementsObj.Engagement_Title__c;
                    LeadObj.Engagement_Overview__c = EngagementsObj.Engagement_Overview__c;
                    LeadObj.Test_Scenarios_provided_by_client__c=EngagementsObj.Test_Scenarios_provided_by_client__c;
                    LeadObj.Preferred_Start_Date__c=EngagementsObj.Start_Date__c;
                    LeadObj.Preferred_End_Date__c=EngagementsObj.End_Date__c;
                    LeadObj.Testing_Type__c=EngagementsObj.Testing_Type__c;
                    LeadObj.Known_Compatibility_Coverage__c=EngagementsObj.Known_Compatibility_Coverage__c;
                    LeadObj.Website_to_be_tested__c=EngagementsObj.Website_URL_to_be_tested__c;

                }
            }

        }     
        catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Exception: '+e);
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'' + e));

        }
    }
```

the test class to the above class is below:

```
@istest
public class NewEngagementRequestController_test {


    static testmethod void Scenario1(){

        Test.startTest();

        Account acc = new Account(name='John Smith');

        insert acc;

        Contact cont = new Contact();
        cont.FirstName='Test1';
        cont.LastName='Test';
        cont.Accountid= acc.id;

        insert cont;

        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Planit Customer Community' limit 1];

        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt12', Email='standarduser12@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing21', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, ContactId = cont.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser12@testorg.com');

        insert u;



        system.runAs(u){

            Lead l = new Lead(lastname='test', company='testcompany', status='new');
            insert l;

           // PageReference pageRef = Page.NewEngagementRequest;
            //Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

            ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(l);

            NewEngagementRequestController Erc = new NewEngagementRequestController(sc);

        }
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

I have checked permission related to this but doesn't seems to work. 
Can you please help me out in this?

Comment: does "Planit Customer Community" profile has all access related to what you're testing?